# what is "dd if=/dev/zero of=/storage2/test4.img bs=1M count=256" usage?

Tags: linux, solaris, dd, storage

I would be thankful if someone can explain me what does following command exactly doing:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/storage2/test4.img bs=1M count=256
```

Comment: write 256MB of zeros to the file `/storage2/test4.img` - use case ... unknown

Comment: It's also not a *good* way to go about doing this. Why is this tagged both Linux and Solaris? Is this maybe from a script for an older version of Solaris? Context might help, but on Linux in 2023, there would have been better ways, depending on *why* this was done (guarantee a non-sparse file? Not this way. Trying to make a zero filled file as quickly as possible? Not this way, either.)

Comment: It would help if you could explain which parts of the documentation of `dd` you do understand and which you don't. That way, answerers can avoid repeating information you already understand and also information you already know didn't help you the last time you read it. Telling you stuff you already know is wasting not only the time of answerers but yours as well, and the same goes for repeating things you already read that didn't help you.

Answer (score 5):

It creates an 256 MB file filled with zeros in the directory /storage2. This can be used as a disk image and formatted and mounted as any disk using a loop device.

See:

- [man dd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html)
- [man mount](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html)
- [Loop device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device)
- Creating blank disk image file for storage in [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667291/create-blank-disk-image-for-file-storage)

Comment: Your definition is not correct. The file is not empty, it is filled with zeroes.

Comment: @RomeoNinov It's empty in the sense of "not containing any (structured) information". It is not empty in the sense "being a sparse file".

Comment: Nitpick: (since it's `dd`) it only does 256 reads of 1 MB each, and writes the results to the file. The result is likely 256 MB, but could be less if the system gives short reads for whatever reason...

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks. Nits gotta be picked when they ripen, otherwise they ferment. Squirrels mistake them for nuts, get drunk, gang up and start causing havoc in the suburbs.

Comment: It also does not necessarily create the `/storage2/test4.img` file.  The file may already have existed and this `dd` command simply fills the first 256MB with 0x00 bytes.